# symfony2 form create with many to one relationship and existing foreign key

Tags: forms, symfony, one-to-many

I'm trying to set a create form for an entity that has a many-to-one relationship with another entity.

These are my entities:

```
class EvntEvents
{

/**
* Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}


/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="EvntSessions", mappedBy="eventFk")
 * 
 * @var ArrayCollection $sessions
 * 
 */
protected $sessions;

/**
 * Add sessions
 *
 * @param Technogym\EventsBundle\Entity\EvntSessions $sessions
 * @return EvntEvents
 */
public function addSession(\Technogym\EventsBundle\Entity\EvntSessions $sessions)
{
$this->sessions[] = $sessions;

return $this;
}

/**
 * Get sessions
 *
 * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getSessions()
{
 return $this->sessions;
}
}
```

The latter entity record already exists so I thought to include its id as an hidden field in the form as follows:

```
$entity = new EvntSessions();
$entity->setEventFk($event);
$form   = $this->createForm('form_sessions', $entity);
```

The form is displayed correctly but on submitting I get the following error:

UnexpectedTypeException: Expected argument of type "object or array", "NULL" given

so I created the relationship before binding the request:

```
$event->addSession($entity);
$entity->setEventFk($event);
```

but I get the following error:

PropertyAccessDeniedException: Property "id" is not public in class "EvntEvents". Maybe you should create the method "setId()"?

So I don't understand where is my mistake. Maybe I don't understand he model behind doctrine relationships?

Comment: can you show your `getId()` function in class EvntEvents

Comment: done, in any case it's a simple getter

Comment: I think this has something to do with an error in your controller code. If you could add the code for the controller in total that would make it much easier to spot the problem.